# JMenuBar at the top in MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, jmenubar

In the Java Desktop Application template used by Netbeans, a menu bar is created with JMenuBar and JMenuItems.

How can I get that bar displayed at the top, where menu bars are displayed in MacOSX instead of in-window, like in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Note: This is outdated information - a more recent answer is needed.

Java applications look like traditional java applications even under OS X.

If you want a native look and feel, there are a few tweaks you have to do.  This article series describes them.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javatomac-140486.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javatomac2-138389.html

This includes setting the Dock icon and text, and integrating with the Applications menu.

I believe that the OS X "wrap jar as an application" utility with XCode sets all these properties automatically.

Comment: Since I wrote the answer, Apple has disowned Java, and the Oracle provided Java 7 works differently.  I have not worked with Java 7 under OS X.

Comment: I've updated the old sun.com link to new ones to the oracle website, but the article images are missing and they are from 2003...

Answer (score 14):

By adding something like this into your code:

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
  System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
}
```

Comment: If I run my app with this argument: -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true, the bar is shown correctly at the top, but if I do this System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true"); on the main method, it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure. I would try to put it as the first code in main() method or System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true"); without if condition (is not met if os.name contains "mac" instead of "Mac" for example) It seems to work on my 10.5.8 Leopard.

Comment: I found that it worked if I placed it just after creating my JFrame (very first thing in main) and before creating my JMenuBar or doing any other modifications to my JFrame. This was under OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).

Comment: The test for "is a Mac" is a bit fragile.  A better approach is to test for the existance of the functionality you need - in this case whether an Apple Java 6-specific class exists or not.

Comment: That test sounds fragile too. What you should be doing is testing whether the Aqua look & feel is actually in use. If you set this system property when using Nimbus, your application will crash, so it's important only to set it when using Aqua.

Comment: Why is the `if` check even necessary? Won't the property simply be ignored if you're not running on a mac?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but I realized that the MenuBar needs to be added to the frame as:

**frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);**

instead of: **frame.add(jMenuBar);**  along with: **System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");** in the main method.

Comment: As of Mojave in 2019, this answer is what was necessary for me