# Javax JMenuBar with Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenubar

When I try to add a JMenuBar to my frame in Mac, it doesn't show up. I assume it's because JMenuBar isn't integrated into the Mac native method. So can anybody help me with the code that I can use to make my bar viewable?

Comment: The menu bar should appear in the frame, until you set `useScreenMenuBar` using any of the approaches suggested. This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513) may help clarify exactly what isn't showing up where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set the `apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar` property to `true` in your `Info.plist`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly it you need to tell the JVM to use the MenuBar like:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```

Then in your JFrame set the menu bar like so:

```
frame.setJMenuBar(new MenuBar());
```

Comment: Instead of new MenuBar() place what your JMenuBar is called. And are you using the java version supplied by apple?

Comment: I know. I'm no noob at java; I just converted to Mac a week ago. And yeah, I am.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following VM argument to the java call:

```
-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
```