# Java/OS X Lion: Setting application name stopped working with JDK1.7

Tags: java, macos, swing, osx-lion, java-7

I hitherto used the following code to set the Application Name (in the top "System" menu bar) on my Apple MacBook. (Actually, I think I copied this from stackoverflow.)

Basically, have a seperate AppLauncher class that uses System.setProperty() to set the application name before creating a new Runnable for the app itself.

Worked just fine.

However, since I downloaded and started using JDK 1.7, the solution stopped working - I'm getting the Class Name instead of the App Name in the menu, just like before I found that solution. I tried googling it, but to no avail.

Here is the defunct code that used to work under JDK 1.6, reduced to the relevant parts:

```
public class AppLauncher {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name",
                "My Application");
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainWindow();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks for suggestions!

ETA: invoking with java -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true still works. Pu8tting the property into Info.plist might work, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Any luck with `-D` or `Info.plist`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513)? It may be unsupported in OpenJDK.

Comment: Hi, yeah the -D seems to do the trick. I will keep Info.plist in the back of my head and try it once I'm there, thanks.

Comment: @trashgod: you should probably add it as an answer so that the question can leave the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that setting the property using `-D` solves the problem.

```
java -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true …
```

Other approaches are mentioned in this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the Info.plist or -D approaches to work (I'm working on distributing a JRuby App, that might have something to do with it), but for me passing the `-Xdock:name` parameter as mentioned in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javatomac-140486.html) under the section "More tinkering with the menu bar" seemed to work great.

Example: `-Xdock:name="My Application"`