# OS X: set application icon when launching Java/Swing application from shellscript

Tags: java, macos, swing

Until now I used `JavaApplicationStub` inside a `.app` directory structure to launch our Java/Swing application on OS X. The dock icon configured in the `Info.plist` works fine.

Now I've tried to launch the application using a shell-script inside the `.app` directory structure, but the dock icon only shows the one configured in `Info.plist` for a very short time and then falls back to the Java default icon. What I need to do that the configured icon remains there?

Comment: *"What I need to do that the configured icon remains there?"*  Deploy that app. using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?

Comment: See also these [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution. I had to add the `-Xdock:icon=<path>` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Window.getIconImages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29) ?

Comment: No, I just used the same application code as before which worked fine with `JavaApplicationStub`.