# Runnable jar doesn't use Apple's methods

Tags: java, jar

I've exported my java program to a runnable jar file, and it works great except for a few methods. When I use apple's methods such as..

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```

..and..

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor");
```

..they work in eclipse, but don't run in the runnable jar. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know why from the snippets, but, according to [Java Runtime System Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html) you could pass them as part of the Java command,

```
java -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar="true" com.example.yourApp
```

Or set them as part of the `System.setProperty`, but you should do so before any part of the AWT/Swing libraries have had a chance to be initialised.

> When setting a property within your application (using
>   System.setProperty), make sure that it is one of the first statements
>   made inside of your main method. Doing so sets the property before AWT
>   is loaded, ensuring that it takes effect.

Or you could package your app as an app bundle, then you could supply the setting as part of the `Info.plist` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955638/how-do-i-move-my-jmenubar-to-the-screen-menu-bar-on-mac-os-x)