# on Mac the .app crashes but underlying sh file runs fine

Tags: java, macos, swing, shell

I have an shell script file which is wrapped up in Mac's .app package.
When I run the .app file the app crashes or sometimes doesn't show the UI.
This is a Java swing application. When I run the same script file from the same current directory it runs fine.

So my .app contents are like below

```
build
->sample.app
 -->Contents
  -->MacOS
    -->sample-mac.sh
```

On the terminal from build directory if I do

```
open sample.app
```

it crashes
if I do
`sh -x sample.app/Contents/MacOS/sample-mac.sh` it runs perfectly

Can you tell me what are the differences in running the app file and underlying script file?

Comment: Not been an expert in the lower aspect of the OS, I might "suggest" that open is trying to perform an execution of the main entry point using a method which can't run shell scripts...but that's just a guess

Comment: For [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513), what is the value of key `CFBundleExecutable` in your `Info.plist`?